# How to re-assign template in emberjs component?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

What I want is when I click on a link of a component, the template will change dynamically with its subsequent state(some other html codes).

What I have done is in init process, every component's template could be displayed dynamically. When I click link Add, Invite or Accept, the property status of component was changed accordingly and function statusChanged is triggered but component's template was still not changed.

(I've spent hours on this and I'm gonna crazy.)

Here's the code on emberjs.jsbin.com:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/laxeqigepu/2/

As the outputs, html has changed and could be logged out. But why layout is not changed?

```
console.log( html );
this.set('layout', Ember.Handlebars.compile(html));
```

Comment: Can you create demo on emberjs.jsbin.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting these cases in your template:

```
//templates/components/contact-invitation.hbs
{{#if zeroStatus}}
  {{#if uidPositive}}
    <a href="#" {{ action "send" }}><i class="success fa fa-plus"></i> Add</a>
  {{#else}}
    <a href="#" {{ action "send" }}><i class="success fa fa-plus"></i> Invite</a>
  {{/if}}
{{#else}}
  {{#if wait}}
    Wait
  {{#else}}
    ...
  {{/if}}
{{/if}}


//components/contact-invitation.js
import Ember from "ember";
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  zeroStatus: function() {
    return this.get('status') === 0;
  }.property('status'),

  uidPositive: function() {
    return this.get('uid') > 0
  }.property('uid')

  //etc.
});
```

This is a little awkward because Handlebars lacks an `{{# else if }}` construct, and also because I don't know much about your domain -- my guess is there's probably a better solution than `zeroStatus`, `oneStatus`, and so on. This does seem to be the idiomatic solution in Ember/Handlebars, though: define properties in the class, and use conditionals based on those properties in the templates.

Comment: This way works. What I need is a right way to use Emberjs, but it's hard to find. Wish this question would help more to find the right way.